# How to transform this SQL Server query to Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I need help to transform this SQL Server query to Entity Framework Core.
It's a many-to-many relation:

- Table Form
- Table Question
- Table LinkFormQuestion (ids of 2 others two , plus a field called Order)

All I need is to get all the question that belong to a form and is order.

The right query is

```
select B.Question, B.YesNo, B.Slider, A.Order   
from LinkFormQuestion as A 
inner join Question as B on A.IdQuestion = B.Id  
where A.IdForm = '74103B08-8AE3-4DB7-8E21-110569D5D1D4' and B.language = 'FR'
order by A.Order
```

The Entity Framework Core C#

```
var Questions =  _formManager
         .Question.GetAll()
         .Include(l => l.LinkFormQuestion)
         .Where(l => l.LinkFormQuestion.Any(A => A.Form.Id == Guid.Parse("74103B08-8AE3-4DB7-8E21-110569D5D1D4")))
         .Where(l => l.language == "FR")
         .AsNoTracking()
         .Select(l => new
            {
                Question=l.Question,
                YesNo=l.YesNo,
                Slider=l.Slider,
                //Order=l.LinkFormQuestion.Where(x=>x.IdQuestion==l.Id).Select(x=>x.Order)
                //Order=l.LinkFormQuestion.Select(x=>x.Order)
         })
         .ToList();
```

The problem here, I don't know how to navigate to linkFormQuestion to get the order.

The L retrieves only rows from the question table.

Comment: Start the query with `LinkFormQuestion` and it will all fall in place.

Comment: Thank you very much Gert, is working. So if I understand, each time I want to manipulate rows from many to many relationship, I always start from the link table rigth?

Comment: I would like to understand,this warning when I run the code Iget this "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory:Warning: The Include operation for navigation: 'l.Question' was ignored because the target navigation is not reachable in the final query results. To configure this warning use the DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings API (event id 'CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning'). ConfigureWarnings can be used when overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or using AddDbContext on the application service provider." Do I need to be worry about?

Comment: That's a lot of words to tell you that an `Include` is ignored (without further consequences) because there's nothing in the end result that can contain the included entities. That often happen with projections (`new { ... }`). And it tells you that you can stop this warning from appearing (which I wouldn't do). Remove the `Include` and you'll get exactly the same result.

Comment: Thanks Gert for the lesson :) I appreciate.